Не считываются данные типа char с помощью Entity Framework
Оффтоп. Такое ощущение, что эта тема пересекается с той, которая указана в вопросе, словно это звенья одной цепи: Не могу добавить данные в БД с помощью Entity Framework
Только сейчас возникает проблема с загрузкой данных из БД.
Есть проект таблицы ContactsInfo в MS SQL:

Её содержимое:

Я загружаю эти данные в контекст данных ApplicationContext, а затем в ContactViewModel:
internal class ContactViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; }
    public string? PhoneType { get; }
    public string? Name { get; }
    public string? Surname { get; }
    public string? Patronymic { get; }
    public char Sex { get; }
    
    public ContactViewModel(Contact Contact)
    {
        ID = Contact.ID;
        PhoneNumber = Contact.PhoneNumber;
        
        using ApplicationContext ApplicationContext = new();
        
        PhoneType = ApplicationContext.PhoneTypes?.FirstOrDefault(PhoneType => PhoneType.ID == Contact.PhoneTypeID)?.PhoneTypeText ?? null;
        
        ContactInfo? ContactInfo = ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo?.FirstOrDefault(ContactInfo => ContactInfo.ID == Contact.ContactInfoID) ?? null;
        Name = ContactInfo?.Name ?? null;
        Surname = ContactInfo?.Surname ?? null;
        Patronymic = ContactInfo?.Patronymic ?? "—";
        Sex = (ContactInfo?.Sex == '\0' ? '?' : ContactInfo?.Sex) ?? '?';
    }
}

Выглядит это так:

Собственно говоря, на этом фото и можно увидеть, что пол почему-то не прогрузился из БД/ApplicationContext и из-за этого поставилась заглушка в виде символа '?'.
Почему это происходит? В отладке значение Sex строки из загруженной таблицы ContactsInfo почему-то равно 0 '\0', что означает нулевой символ (null character).

Вопрос — почему? С другими данными же всё в порядке, они загружаются правильно. Эта какая-то особенность типа char? Или char(1) в БД?

Заменить char на nchar.

Какой подход использовался: Code First или Database First?

@AlexanderPetrov, 1) Вижу, вы поправили комментарий, хорошо. Но почему вы предлагаете заменить тип? Давайте разберёмся почему вообще происходит обнуление данных (Обновлено: к тому же это не помогло). 2) Использовался подход Code First.

@AlexanderPetrov, нет, всё таки хорошо подумав, я могу сказать, что использовался подход Database First — я же сначала создал БД с таблицами, а затем уже создавал классы моделей в программе.

просто замените в коде char на string, насколько я знаю EF Core не умеет мапить char(1) на char, в итоге в char Sex хранится значение по умолчанию \0. Ещё лучше - заменить на bool и напишите конвертер из строки в bool и наоборот. Ну а ещё лучше - code first

@iikuzmychov, да, изменение char на string в коде помогло, теперь пол считывается и отображается в таблице DataGrid, спасибо! А в БД тип так я и оставил как char(1). Только это же всё равно будет костылём, как его не назови. Ну вот какое логичное объяснение тому, что EF не может промапить char? Кстати, EF Core не страдает такой проблемой, ему наоборот удалось успешно считать char(1) и добавить его в свойство char.

В C# строки юникодные: UTF-16. Следовательно char в C# имеет размер два байта. Между тем char в Sql Server имеет размер один байт. Поэтому при записи половина данных теряется.
